# R filter shapefiles with dplyr

Tags: shapefile, r, leaflet

How to filter shapefiles data in R with dplyr and then put it in a leaflet map?

not reproducible example sorry:

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)

lines<- readShapeLines("test",verbose=TRUE, proj4string=XXX)
lines@data<-lines@data %>%
  filter(X>400,Y=="YES") 

m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m %>%addPolylines(data=lines,col="blue")
```

I woulk like to make a leaflet map only with the data selected (attribute X>400 and attribute Y =="YES") ,

"addPolylines(data=lines)" add all lines in the shapefiles

(do I need to merge lines@data with lines?)

Comment: Could you please supply more details on what you are trying to do (e.g. how do you want to filter your shapefile?) and what your script is doing?

Comment: You have to use the `subset` method (see `?subset.Spatial`): `subset(lines, X > 400 & Y=="YES")`; or use indexing via `[]`. Your example filters just the data frame and not the lines.

Comment: @Aaron The data of my shapefile contain two attributes X and Y that I would like to filter with dplyr and then create a leaflet map of the results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is one of the first links that appear when you search  how to filter a spatial file with dplyr I think an update is due. You now could simply transform your shapefile to an SF object and filter with dplyr like verbs. You could try something like this:

```
lines <- st_as_sf(lines)
lines <- lines %>%
    dplyr::filter(X>400 & Y=="YES")
```

Answer (score 15):

You have to use the subset method (see `?subset.Spatial`):

```
 subset(lines, X > 400 & Y=="YES")
```

Alternatively you can use indexing operations via `[]`:

```
 lines[lines$X > 400 & lines$Y=="YES", ]
```

Your `dplyr` code just filters the data frame, but not the geometry.